# Flavor AndroidManifest.xml conflicting with main AndroidManifest.xml, no icons upon installation

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have one flavor, and a main codebase. I can switch to the flavor and the project runs, and I can switch back to the main codebase and the project runs, but neither of these projects will display icons. I do not know why, my only assumption is that something is wrong with my declarations and attributes added to intent-filer

Flavor AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.flavor.application.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:name">

    <!-- main launcher Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.flavor.activity.RegistrationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.flavor.activity.RegistrationActivity"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Main AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.application.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:name">

    <!-- main launcher Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.RegistrationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.activity.RegistrationActivity"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

My build gradle is setup as the following

```
productFlavors {
    standard {
        applicationId 'com.example'
        manifestPlaceholders = [package_name: "com.example", primary_lang: "en"]
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
    }
    legacyTest {
        applicationId 'com.example.flavor.test'
        manifestPlaceholders = [package_name: "com.example.flavor.test",
                                target      : "Test", primary_lang: "en"]
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
    }
}
```

The RegistrationActivity class is different for the Flavor and the main code base. There is no overriding going on, and I believe that since I am using a different package these are effectively acting as different classes which is what I want. But my question is, how come with the Manifest merger I cannot have separate app icons, my flavor icons and my main app icons? Nothing is being displayed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so its the way I setup my intent filters. I had to separate them in the following structure

Flavor AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
            android:name="com.example.flavor.activity.RegistrationActivity"
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Main AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
            android:name="com.example.activity.RegistrationActivity"
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I do not understand the technical reasons why this format works, but grouping everything under one intent-filter will cause issues, such as error at runtime or no app icon. Cheers